# Ethereum block chain extracter and parser like blocksci

Tags: parser, query

I'm new to ethereum and I would like to develop an analyzing framework for ethereum. Is there a blockchain extractor and a parser to similar to blocksci available for ethereum and support analyzing of blockchain data.